# Cannot find Alfresco Repository and login dont works

Tags: alfresco

first of all i want to say, that i tried almost every advice on stackoverflow and nothing works. I tried to install alfresco on Windows server 2019 with tutorial from official documentation.

When i try to login with default username/passsword:admin/admin it says this "Your authentication details haven't been recognized or Alfresco Content Services may not be available at this time."

Alfresco version:7.2
Tomcat Version: 8.5.78
Postgre version:14.2

Tutorial used : https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/community/install/zip/tomcat/#install-application-server

When enter to website: http:\localhost:8080 alfresco says that it cant find repository:

"Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)"

Here is some logs:

tomcat8-stdout.2022-05-16 LOG:

```
2022-05-16 08:36:47 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized.
2022-05-16 08:37:27,397  WARN  [heartbeat.datasender.HBDataSenderServiceBuilder] [localhost-startStop-1] Setting the Heartbeat sender cron with property 'heartbeat.sender.cronExpression' is no longer supported.
2022-05-16 08:37:27,631  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
2022-05-16 08:37:27,631  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.1-metadata-query-indexes
2022-05-16 08:37:27,631  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.2-remove-jbpm-tables-from-db
2022-05-16 08:37:27,631  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V6.3-add-indexes-node-transaction
2022-05-16 08:37:27,631  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V7.1.0-remove-alf_server-table
2022-05-16 08:37:28,141  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco' with user 'alfresco'.
2022-05-16 08:37:28,141  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database PostgreSQL version 14.2
2022-05-16 08:37:35,739  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2022-05-16 08:37:36,038  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
2022-05-16 08:37:41,048  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
2022-05-16 08:37:41,064  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
2022-05-16 08:37:44,431  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
2022-05-16 08:37:44,462  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted] complete
2022-05-16 08:37:44,540  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Connecting to database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco, UserName=alfresco, PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
2022-05-16 08:37:44,540  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Schema managed by database dialect org.alfresco.repo.domain.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.
2022-05-16 08:37:44,898  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Applied patches detected: 10
2022-05-16 08:37:45,011  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Checking and patching Alfresco tables took 113 ms
2022-05-16 08:37:45,055  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Activiti tables need to be checked for patches
2022-05-16 08:37:45,086  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Checking and patching Activiti tables took 31 ms
2022-05-16 08:37:45,133  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Checking that all patches have been applied took 47 ms
2022-05-16 08:37:45,133  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Updating the DB schema took 593 ms
2022-05-16 08:37:45,133  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] No changes were made to the schema.
2022-05-16 08:37:45,300  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04160002 Keystores are invalid
    at org.alfresco.encryption.EncryptionChecker$1.execute(EncryptionChecker.java:78)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.EncryptionChecker$1.execute(EncryptionChecker.java:1)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:319)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.EncryptionChecker.onBootstrap(EncryptionChecker.java:67)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:232)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:217)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1881)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04160001 Failed to create key: metadata
 in key store: 
   Location: /srv/alfresco/alf_data/keystore/keystore
   Provider: null
   Type:     pkcs12
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.createKey(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:664)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.validateKeys(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:915)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.validateKeys(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:188)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.KeyStoreChecker.validateKeyStores(KeyStoreChecker.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.EncryptionChecker$1.execute(EncryptionChecker.java:73)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04160000 Unable to get secret key: no key information is provided
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.getSecretKey(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:775)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.createKey(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:642)
    ... 33 more
2022-05-16 08:37:45,493  WARN  [context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiEngineInitializer.onShutdown(ActivitiEngineInitializer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:232)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:202)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:217)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1881)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-05-16 08:37:45,571  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopping 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
2022-05-16 08:37:45,571  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopped 'ContentStore' subsystem, ID: [ContentStore, managed, unencrypted]
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "officeToImageViaPdf" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "pdfToImageViaPng" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "iWorksToImageViaJpg" references the transformOptions (imageMagickOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "outlookMsg2Image" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "outlookMsg2Pdf" references the transformOptions (tikaOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "rfc822ToImage" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "textToImageViaPdf" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "ooXmlToImageViaText" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "archiveToImageViaText" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "ooXmlToPdfViaText" references the transformOptions (tikaOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "archiveToPdfViaText2" references the transformOptions (archiveOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "libreofficeToPdfBoxViaPdf" references the transformOptions (pdfboxOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "textBasedToImageViaText" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "outlookMsgToLibreofficeViaText" references the transformOptions (tikaOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "htmlToImageViaTXT" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  WARN  [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "rfc822ToPdf" ignored as step transforms ("rfc822", "libreoffice") do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  WARN  [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Transformer "htmlToPdfViaTXT" ignored as step transforms ("string", "libreoffice") do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,794  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "officeToImageViaPdf" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "pdfToImageViaPng" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "iWorksToImageViaJpg" references the transformOptions (imageMagickOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "outlookMsg2Image" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "outlookMsg2Pdf" references the transformOptions (tikaOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "rfc822ToImage" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "textToImageViaPdf" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "ooXmlToImageViaText" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "archiveToImageViaText" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "ooXmlToPdfViaText" references the transformOptions (tikaOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "archiveToPdfViaText2" references the transformOptions (archiveOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "libreofficeToPdfBoxViaPdf" references the transformOptions (pdfboxOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "textBasedToImageViaText" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "outlookMsgToLibreofficeViaText" references the transformOptions (tikaOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  ERROR [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "htmlToImageViaTXT" references the transformOptions (pdfRendererOptions) which do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  WARN  [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "rfc822ToPdf" ignored as step transforms ("rfc822", "libreoffice") do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,810  WARN  [content.transform.LocalTransformServiceRegistry] [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Transformer "htmlToPdfViaTXT" ignored as step transforms ("string", "libreoffice") do not exist. Read from resource alfresco/transforms/0100-basePipelines.json
2022-05-16 08:37:45,919  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopping 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2022-05-16 08:37:45,919  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopped 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2022-05-16 08:38:07,879  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2022-05-16 08:38:07,915  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 2022-05-16 08:38:07,916  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2022-05-16 08:38:07,917  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,582  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 383 Web Scripts (+0 failed), 401 URLs
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,582  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 8 Package Description Documents (+0 failed) 
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,582  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 0 Schema Description Documents (+0 failed) 
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,660  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntimeContainer] [localhost-startStop-1] Initialised Surf Container Web Script Container (in 4723.9746ms)
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,660  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,660  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,692  INFO  [site.servlet.AIMSFilter] [localhost-startStop-1] Initializing the AIMS filter.
 2022-05-16 08:38:12,692  INFO  [site.servlet.AIMSFilter] [localhost-startStop-1] AIMS filter initialized.
 2022-05-16 08:38:19,523  INFO  [web.site.EditionInterceptor] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] Unable to retrieve License information from Alfresco: 404
```

Comment: Supply a valid keystore to Alfresco? https://docs.alfresco.com/search-services/latest/config/keys/ + https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ssl-generator

Comment: Tried to go through tutorial that you suggest but it didnt work - same error in tomcat8-stdout.2022-05-17 :
 04170006 Keystores are invalid
04170005 Failed to create key: metadata
 in key store: 
   Location: /srv/alfresco/alf_data/keystore/keystore
   Provider: null

Comment: I start to thinking that i have problem with folder structure:
Alfresco-global.properties:
 dir.root=/srv/alfresco/alf_data
 dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore

C:\Alfresco\
alfresco-content-services
alfresco-search-services
alfresco-ssl-generator-master
alfresco-tomcat-apache
alf_data
modules

C:\Alfresco\alfresco-content-services
amps
bin
keystore
licenses
web-server

C:\Alfresco\alfresco-tomcat-apache

alf_data
bin
conf
keystores
lib
logs
modules
shared
temp
webapps
work